# sonar issue count by description (message) and severity

Tags: sonarqube

How can I get a sonar report of all issues by severity and description, e.g.:

```
Critical
  wtf 11
  wtff?? 3

Major
  foonly 12

Minor
  silliness 17

...
```

So far I have come up with using the Sonar web services to get a list of issues and then processing that with JQ.  It seems that there should be an easier way.

==== Further description ===

I have legacy code with 6000+ sonar issues, I don't want to navigate to the individual files. I want a summary so I can decide out what to fix and what to leave. What I really want is a query language that will produce a custom report, or a simple description of the DB schema so I can use SQL and get a flat table that I can further process as needed, not PDF or HTML or XML or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The [Issues Report Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Issues+Report+Plugin) can give you such kind of report.

But such report is static and you'll completely miss the ability to drilldown and navigate through the sources.